# Swift: JSON file from URL instead of local

Tags: json, xcode, swift

Right now I have this:

```
let path : String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("jsonFile", ofType: "json") as String!
    let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) as NSData!
    let readableJSON = JSON(data :jsonData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil)
```

But I want to receive the file from a url, and not have it in my app.

Comment: what did you try so far? any code example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read through some of apple docs: [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/) and [NSURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSession_class/)

Here is a quick solution for how to achieve this though.

```
func fetchDetailsFromServer() {
    let urlPath = "Server URL to Fetch JSON"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        println("Task completed")
        if(error != nil) {
            // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var err: NSError?
        if let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary {
            if(err != nil) {
                // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
                println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
            }

            // Use your jsonResult appropriately here
        }
    })

    // The task is just an object with all these properties set
    // In order to actually make the web request, we need to "resume"
    task.resume()
}
```